# What gets called before oncreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have below code and want to know what gets called before `onCreate()` because it shows blank screen before the activity(Tabbed activity) gets called. What can be done for this to avoid showing blank screen ?

I can't even use onAttach as my Class is extending **AppCompatActivity** and implements `OnMapReadyCallback`,`PlaceSelectionListener`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
  TabHost tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
  tab.setup();

  TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("Search");
  spec1.setIndicator("Search");
  spec1.setContent(R.id.layout1);
  tab.addTab(spec1);

  TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("Settings");
  spec2.setIndicator("Settings");
  spec2.setContent(R.id.layout2);
  tab.addTab(spec2);

  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }
}
```

Comment: in case of fragments `onAttach()` is called before `onCreate()`. [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677812/why-is-onattach-called-before-oncreate)

Comment: My Class is extending AppCompatActivity and implements OnMapReadyCallback,PlaceSelectionListener. So I can't use OnAttach()

Comment: theApplication class maybe?

Comment: before anything `Manifest.xml` is called

Comment: Then it would probably due to instantiation of your application instance. To avoid this try doing bulkier work in some other thread.

Answer (score 2):

in case of activity is created the following function is called:

```
onCreate()

onStart()   

onResume()

onPause()

onStop()

onDestroy()

onRestart()
```

and when fragment is made in an activity then:

```
onAttach()

onCreate() 

onCreateView() 

onActivityCreated()

 onCreateView() 

onStart()

onResume()

onPause() 

onStop()

onDestroyView()

onDestroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid the blank screen, you can use below code. It works !!

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
and use it with your activity in AndroidManifest as:

<activity android:name=".ActivitySplash" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

Answer (score 1):

To investigate slow loads and white screens, you should use Android's `TraceView` feature: `MethodTracing`.

If you have a class extending `Application` in your project add `Debug.startMethodTracing()` as the first line in its `onCreate` method, if you don't have an `Application` class, add this line as the first line of your `Activity`'s `onCreate`.

Later, in your activity's onResume, or even later if you want, you can call `Debug.stopMethodTracing()` to stop tracing.

You can view the Trace files created in Studio to get a sense of which methods took long and why.

See docs here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

Other profiling tools by Android:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html#monitors

Answer (score 1):

In `Activity`, `attachBaseContext` is called before `onCreate`. You can create a `Log` to test this.

Read more in [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity).

Or you can see all methods is called in the order in `AppCompatActivity.java`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is called in the activity before onCreate,look the image below

**BUT** before any activity is created, an applicaton instance is instanciated:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982161/%ce%a6xoc%c4%99-%ec%9b%83-%d0%9fepe%c3%bapa-%e3%83%84) says, there is no method called before `onCreate()`. You can look at the following diagram taken from [Complete Android Fragment & Activity Lifecycle](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle):

[image]